# Get Array with Keys Containing in Other Array Of Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array A:

```
A = Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
    [3] => key4
)
```

And an array B:

```
B = Array
(
    [key1] => some_value
    [key6] => some_value
    [key3] => some_value
)
```

How can I produce this array without using a loop:

```
C = Array
(
    [key1] => some_value
    [key3] => some_value
)
```

`[key6] => some_value` would not be included since `key6` is not part of array A.

Comment: let the array function incantations begin

Comment: `$c = array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a));`

Comment: Perfect! Your spell works. :)